# Prestashop 1.7 Installation Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP Too many redirects

Tags: apache, ubuntu, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to install Prestashop 1.7 on an Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP droplet from Digitalocean.

After copying Prestashop source files under a `presta` folder in `/var/www/html`, when accessing `http://95.85.6.69/presta/` in the browser I am getting redirected to `http://95.85.6.69/presta/install/index.php?step=welcome` which is cool, except, it keeps on redirecting until I am getting: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` thrown back at me.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a config I am missing? How can I surpass that error?

[image: chrome dev tools -> network]

The image above is an addition to the error description.

*P.S: Ignore the differences in IPs as they are the result of multiple deployments of the same snapshot, ubuntu 14.04 LAMP, on Digitalocean.*

Comment: was the shop installed in the previous folder?

Comment: You can find a patch here http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/BOOM-1802

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you enabled the curl extension? I had the same problem couple days ago. After investigating the problem, I found out that the curl extension wasn't enabled and Prestashop doesn't throw any errors if it is not enabled.

Comment: Accepted this answer, but with respect to John Simon's answer that enable curl extension correctly.

Comment: Also, important to note, redirects were caused as well by not having the correct folder/files permissions. Using `chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/presta-install-dir/` to set the ownership to the apache daemon will solve the issue.

Comment: It would be a great idea for our fellow community members here, if you edited your answer and included the stuff I wrote in the comment above

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Then restart the apache2 server using

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the commands, I've accepted Jack's answer because he added a little explanation as well, but kudos for this :+1:

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following links, it might be possible that you find a solution for this problem:

https://forum.c4.cz/prestashop-1-7-0-4-instalace-a-chyba-too-many-redirects-t7692.html
https://serverfault.com/questions/824940/prestashop-1-7-too-many-redirects-on-frontend-shop

Answer (score 0):

After installing PrestaShop on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS I had the same issue. Everything needed is installed and running. I checked the logs and there where no errors when loading the page, but the issue persisted. 
I tried loading the Admin panel and was able to login. After reading in some simular issues I wondered if it had to do with SSL, that I set up with the domain.
Long Story short, if you can reach the admin panel check the shop settings and if SSL is aktivated and is aktivated for all pages. That solved the issue for me.